# Can't reference SSIS variables in script task

Tags: ssis

I have a very simple SSIS package and an absurdly simple Script task

```
    var x = Dts.Variables["User::OrderPath"];
```

That fails with:

> The element cannot be found in a collection. This error happens when
>   you try to retrieve an element from a collection on a container during
>   execution of the package and the element is not there.

I have a variable, `OrderPath`, that is scoped to the package.  Any time I try to add the variable to the script's ReadOnlyVariables, it disappears whenever I execute the task.

This really shouldn't be this difficult so I assume I'm missing something monumentally basic.  Any idea what that might be?

Comment: You click to add the variable into the readonly collection and after doing whatever with the task, the variable *disappears*? Also, what if you attempt to access the variable by its ordinal position `x=Dts.Variables[0]` Final comment, do note that `x` will be an instance of an SSIS Variable. Generally, you're looking to access the `Value` property of that Variable.

Comment: Thansk, Bill.  Yes, it disappears, as odd or wrong as that may seem.  I've not yet tried ordinal reference, we'll see how that goes.  Thanks on the Value point.  Yes, that's what I'm ultimately doing, but by the time of posting was trying to distill it down as simply as possible.

Comment: That smells very wrong. You might want to ensure you have the latest and greatest bits for your visual studio, sql server and windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

When accessing variables through the `Dts.Variables` collection, you do **not** prefix the variable name with the namespace; thus

```cs
var x = Dts.Variables["User::OrderPath"];
```

fails, while

```cs
var x = Dts.Variables["OrderPath"];
```

succeeds. (Assuming, of course, that `OrderPath` is added to either the `ReadWriteVariables` or `ReadOnlyVariables` task properties.)

See [Using Variables in the Script Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx) in MSDN for another example.

Comment: Thanks, Edmund.  I attempted this variation as well.  I have to wonder if the issue isn't tied more closely to my or it's inability to KEEP the variable properties (I select them time and time again, but after execution, they are gone).

Comment: How are you adding OrderPath to the `ReadOnlyVariables` list?

Comment: I've tried both selecting from the list and manually typing the values (with and without the "User::").  They generally show and appear to stay (OK and re-enter, etc.) right up until I run.